# How to convert $\ln x - \ln y$ into a more accurate floating point representation?

Tags: logarithms, approximation, floating-point

I have an equation $\ln(x) - \ln(y)$ where x and y are very close to eachother. For example if $x = 5.1234$ then something like $fl(\ln(5.1234)) = 1.6338$ (with 4 significant digits). If $y = 5.1233$ then this creates a loss of significant digits which makes the floating point approximation very inaccurate with the actual value.

I need to re-write this to make it more accurate so I re-wrote it like this: $\ln x - \ln y = \ln(\frac{x}{y})$. Unfortunately, if I do something like $\ln(\frac{5.1234}{5.1233})$ then $(\frac{5.1234}{5.1233})$ = 1.000019519 which is 1.0000 in floating point so it's still very inaccurate. Is there some other way to re-write this to make the floating point value more accurate?

Comment: How do you get your  value $1.000019519$? This is off-by-one.
$$\ln\frac{5.1234}{5.1233} \approx 0.00001951880951\approx 0.19519\cdot 10^{-4}$$

Comment: When calculating floating point values, you need to calculate the floating point representation at every single step. So I'd need to start with fl(x/y) which is 1.0000 if we use 4 sig digits and then we add the natural log. So it goes fl(ln(fl(x/y))).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function $\mathrm{log1p}$ if available. Otherwise the first term of the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+z)= z + O(z^2)$ gives

$$\ln\frac{5.1234}{5.1233} =  \ln\frac{5.1234+5.1233-5.1233}{5.1233}=
\ln\left(1+\frac{0.0001}{5.1233}\right)
\approx \frac{0.0001}{5.1233} $$
$$\approx 0.1951866961 \cdot 10^{-4} \approx 0.19519\cdot 10^{-4}$$

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This answer assumes your inputs are approximation (i.e., have a finite number of significant figures, with $5.1234$ approximating some unknowable "true" quantity $5.1234\pm 10^{-4}$. If for some reason $5.1234$ is an *exact* number (has infinite significant figures) then this answer is moot and you should use `log1p`.

You're right to use the identity
$$\log x - \log y = \log(x/y)$$
as this avoids catastrophic cancellation of the results of the $\log$ functions. If you get numerical zero, that's still more accurate than whatever noise comes out of catastrophic cancellation.

Other than that, it's not clear what you're hoping for. Math isn't magic; you can't recover information that's been lost.
$$\log\left(5.1234+\epsilon\cdot 10^{-4}\right) - \log 5.1233 \approx 0.0000195185 + 0.0000195183 \epsilon$$
for representation error $|\epsilon|<1$, so you cannot hope for any kind of accurate result.

As gammatester says in his answer, you could use `log1p`, but it's not actually all that useful in this case unless you somehow know $x-y$ to higher precision than $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @JoshSusa How are you measuring the error? The question you should be asking is, "given $65.45 \pm 0.01$ and $65.44\pm 0.01$, which way should I calculate to minimize the interval of possible answers?" Hint: you will get terrible answers *no matter what you do* if you only have one sig fig difference between the two inputs.

Comment: @JoshSusa Putting it differently, if $x$ and $y$ are **exact** numbers, then you can calculate $x-y$ exactly and hence should use `log1p`. My answers assumes $x$ and $y$ are floating-point approximations of some measured quantity whose exact values are unknown.

Comment: @JoshSusa "The true value is just that equation" No, once again, it matters whether your $65.45$ has four, or infinite, significant figures.